# R programming - improving a minimal spanning tree plot using {ape}

Tags: r

I tried the following codes to plot minimal spanning tree:

```
library(ape)
mstree <-mst(distmat) #distmat is a distance matrix
plot(mstree, x1 = xycoordinates[,1], x2 = xycoordinates[,2])
```

if I command the above lines, I do get a minimal spanning tree diagram according to the distance matrix I specified, yet the graph looks bit boring because everything is black....if I want to change the colour of the tree "branches" into blue (i.e. from being black), how can  I do that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

The `edge.color` parameter controls that color. You can code it to vary by clade, etc, to make the trees even more informative.

```
plot(mstree, edge.color="blue", x1 = xycoordinates[,1], x2 = xycoordinates[,2])
```

There are all kinds of good tips in [the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/ape.pdf) too.

**EDIT**: 
As @sdittmar pointed out, this only works for `phylo` objects and not `mst` plots! To change the colors of the lines (and labels) in a minimum spanning tree, you can set `par(fg="blue")` before invoking the `plot` command.  If you change `par(col="red")`, it will set the color of the labels.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
require(ape)
require(stats)
M = mst(dist(matrix(runif(200), 10, 5)))
par(fg="blue")
par(col="red")
plot(M)
```

[image: colored plot of minimum spanning tree]

Comment: `edge.color` graphics parameter only works for `plot.phylo` but not for `plot.mst`!